What does the subscript "F" in the glmnet multi-task regression optimization problem define?
I was planning on using the glmnet implementation of ElasticNet multi-target regression. I was examining the documentation to accurately describe the technique in a manuscriptI am writing.
The optimization problem for the ElasticNet model is defined as:
$
\min_{(\beta_0, \beta) \in \mathbb{R}^{(p+1) \times K}} \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N \|y_i - \beta_0 - \beta^T x_i\|_F^2 + \lambda \left[ (1 - \alpha) \frac{\|\beta\|_F^2}{2} + \alpha \sum_{j=1}^p \|\beta_j\|_2 \right]
$
This is the glmnet article where I obtained that definition.
What is the subscript "F" denote? This appears in the L2 regularization term and in the definition of MSE term.

I'm an idiot, it is the Frobenius Norm (Wikipedia.
